# Increase in target emission rate (TER) when using a air source heat pump (ASHP) in standard assessment procedure (SAP) calculation

Tags: modeling, heating-systems, building-design, building-physics, renewable-energy

I am running a SAP calculation on a proposed building which will be utilising a 8.5 kW ASHP for space and water heating. I am also running a comparative analysis against a mains gas boiler to show the reduction in dwelling emission rate (DER).

I have noticed that when specing the heat pump in my model the TER shoots up from 14.49 kgCO<sub>2</sub>/yr/m<sup>2</sup> (in the gas powered model) to 21.5 kgCO<sub>2</sub>/yr/m<sup>2</sup>. This is having a pretty massive impact on the percentage improvement of DER over TER between models.

Can any one explain why this happens? I cannot find an explanation elsewhere and I would hate to overstate the potential improvement the heat pump brings.

Cheers

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to try [Unmet Hours](https://unmethours.com/questions/) -- it's a building energy modeling group, very similar to SE (actually they had an [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal at one point, but not enough momentum back then).

Comment: Those look like [CO2 factor](https://www.eia.gov/environment/emissions/co2_vol_mass.php) proportions for heating oil vs coal fired base load. Are you sure the heat pump's coefficient of performance is included in those numbers? Please post your entire comparative analysis.